# some help on the group of unknotted

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, knot-theory

Show that the group of the unknotted $K=\{(z_z,z_2)\in \mathbb{S^3} : |z_1|=1 \}$ is infinite cyclic. where $\mathbb{S^3}$ is to be considering as the unit vectors in $\mathbb{C^2}\cong \mathbb{R^4}$.

---

My attempt was to take $A=\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{S^3}: |z_1|^{2} \leq |z_2|^{2}\}$ and $B=\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{S^3}: |z_1|^{2} \geq |z_2|^{2}\}$ and to show that they are both homeomorphic to the solid torus -which I don't know if it is easy  to find a homeomorphism or not- now $A\cap B$ is a torus, and we can consider the unknotted as the center circle "center line" in $A$, so $K=\{(z_z,z_2)\in A: |z_2|=0\}$ hence the boundary of $A$ is a torus ($\cong A \cap B$ ) which is deformation retract of $A-K$, now what can I say about $B$?.

Something else which I need some help too is to understand: the torus $\cong A \cap B$ is the common boundary of both $A$ and $B$ where $A$ and $B$ are both solid tori.. I cannot imagine this! something wrong or it is hard to imagine?

Comment: Ok! i took $A=\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{S^3}: {z_1}^{2} \leq {z_2}^{2}\}$ and $B=\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{S^3}: {z_1}^{2} \geq {z_2}^{2}\}$ then $A\cup B= \mathbb{S^3}$ and $A \cap B= T$ torus

Comment: You are missing absolute values? **I suggest you explain what you did in the body of the question itself** (if anything, because comments do not allow you to preview and have limited editing capabilites)

Comment: I want to show that $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic to the solid torus, and I will take the center line in $A$ then..

Comment: yes i missed them ..

Comment: «Obvious» in this case means «I can find an homeo to a torus if I want», and the only way to check if it obvious for you or not is to... find an homeo to the torus.

Comment: I meant it must have a proof or no? honestly! it is not obvious to me

Comment: The claim that $A$ is homeo to a solid torus of course needs a proof!

Comment: In any case, have you tried using van Kampen's theorem?

Comment: i edited the word, no i did not because they are closed subsets

Comment: Well... you can try enlarging them to open ones!

Comment: I think if i can prove that $B$ is deformation  retract of$S^3 -K$ then I am almost done, it seems easy, and i think it is, but i cant see it!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8341/discussion-between-danial-and-mariano-suarez-alvarez)